# System String^ adding characters to stack (Visual C++)

Tags: string, visual-studio, visual-c++, char, c++-cli

I'm trying to get characters from a String^ to put into a stack to use later, but when I check what actually gets put in it always has a number in front of it which messes up using it later (e.g. If I try to get a "-" character from within my string it shows as " 45 "-" ").

```
String^ input = "8-2";
char Temp = input[1];
```

The Temp variable will show as = 45 "-"

I'd like it to just save to the char as "-" only so I add it to a stack and call it later with Peek() but I can't figure out how.

Comment: ***And what is ' ^ ' in ' String^ ' ?*** That is c++-cli not standard c++.

Comment: That is just the way the debugger displays a `char` value, it's like it is 1971 again.  Maybe you meant to use `Char` instead, given that the String type stores a Unicode string.  `char` is legacy C, an 8-bit type, elements of a String fit in a `wchar_t` or `System::Char`.

Answer (score 0):

45 is the ASCII code of the character `-`. It's showing you your data as both integer and character.

Answer (score 0):

"char" (when using C++/CLI) is a C/C++ type (a one-byte representation of a 'character').  It's not a .NET type.  Try `Char` (e.g. `System::Char`) instead and see if that works.